# CSS: How to darker color in li tag example first li color orange and last li color red

Tags: css, colors, less, html-lists

My purpose is display 5 question. The first is the easiest one and the last is the hardest one. I want to change around 10% darker for each li tag.
Is it posiple useing CSS or LESS. If yes how?
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Just assign them a class from question 1 `class = 'easy1'` through 5 `class = 'easy5'` and define those in css.

Answer (score 0):

It's what your looking for?

```css
.q1 {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 
}

.q2 {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 
}

.q3 {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 
}

.q4 {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 
}

.q5 {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="q1">Question 1</li>
  <li class="q2">Question 2</li>
  <li class="q3">Question 3</li>
  <li class="q4">Question 4</li>
  <li class="q5">Question 5</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I work it out with less

html

```
<a href="#"> <li class="q1">1. The partners enjoy cool</li> </a>
 <a href="#"> <li class="q2">2. The partners enjoy cool</li></a>
 <a href="#"> <li class="q3">3. The partners enjoy cool</li></a>
 <a href="#"> <li class="q4">4. The partners enjoy cool</li></a>
 <a href="#"> <li class="q5">5. The partners enjoy cool</li></a>
```

LESS

```
 @color:orange;
    .q1{
        background-color: @color;
    }
    .q2{
        background-color:darken(@color,5%);
    }
    .q3{
        background-color:darken(@color,10%);
    }
    .q4{
        background-color:darken(@color,15%);
    }
    .q5{
        background-color:darken(@color,20%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop in LESS and to go from orange to red you can use `spin` instead `darken`:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="difficulty-1">element 1</li>
  <li class="difficulty-2">element 2</li>
  <li class="difficulty-3">element 3</li>
  <li class="difficulty-4">element 4</li>
  <li class="difficulty-5">element 0</li>
</ul>
```

**LESS**

```
.elements(5);

@color:orange;
.elements(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

  .difficulty-@{i} {
    color: spin(@color,(@i - 1)*-10%);
  }
  .elements(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**OUTPUT CSS**

```
.difficulty-1 {
  color: #ffa500;
}
.difficulty-2 {
  color: #ff7b00;
}
.difficulty-3 {
  color: #ff5000;
}
.difficulty-4 {
  color: #ff2600;
}
.difficulty-5 {
  color: #ff0005;
}
```